# opposite of "top" in sql server, without using order by, there are no keys/indices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve the bottom 10 results from a sql server table. I want them to be the last 10 records that were inserted, how can I do this ?

I want to write `select bottom 10 * from mytable` however this does not exist (afaik).

I want the last 10 rows inserted. 
There is no timestamp.

Comment: I don't think `top` does what you think it does. Also, what is the primary key / unique id on the table - is it a SQLServer identity or guid?

Comment: @MarkBannister there is no pk

Comment: It sounds like you need to alter the schema of your table to add *something* to determine last insert order -- if you don't (ever) need to support merge replication, an IDENTITY relationship may suffice; Otherwise an inserted time stamp would be required (handy for auditing, too).

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Is there any kind of unique index/unique identifier of any type on the table?

Comment: ***shudders*** and yes I know this may be deemed as nonconstructive; but wow...  I'm reminded of myth-busters: I reject your reality and substitute my own.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - If it is a one-off, can you just select the whole table and pick out the last 10 records by hand?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Be aware, you still *can't* be *absolutely certain* that they were the last 10 records inserted.  Good luck though :)

Comment: @Dems why not if I know query plan has not changed,there have been no data changes or queries since insertion ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - That's what everyone here is trying to tell you.  No matter what you did or did not do, SQL Server's code *only* guarantees the order when an ORDER BY is specified.  It *never* guarantees the order without one.  So, the short answer to "why?" is "because that's the way SQL Server is written".  It seems *possible*, maybe even *likely* that you'll get the correct order, but it will *never* be *guaranteed*.  Sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't.

There is no guarantee at all that the last 10 records returned by `select * from mytable` will be the last 10 inserted. There is no default ordering that is used.

You need an `ORDER BY` on an appropriate column reflecting insert order.

Comment: There is no such thing as default order and that's by design. Enforcing a deterministic order when no ORDER BY clause is set would just add extra overhead for no good reason. [Alright, the comment I was replying was just removed...]

Comment: when I do select top 10 * from mytable it does indeed return them in insertion order ... ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky The results are only in "insert order" if there are no joins, conditional statements, and nobody has chosen to rewrite the SQL query engine recently (i.e. this behaviour is coincidental, and not guaranteed)

Comment: ... and the table has not been optimized, moved to another disk or reloaded from a backup.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - It might do at the moment but this isn't guaranteed and won't be the case after some data changes. Assuming your table is a heap you will likely get an allocation ordered scan in order of where the pages happen to be in the file. There is no guarantee that new pages will be allocated after existing pages or that it will scan them in order anyway. Additionally new rows can get added into replace previously deleted rows. If you need this you need to add an appropriate monotonically increasing column.

Comment: @MartinSmith if no data changes have occurred, its ok ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Who knows? As I said above there is no guarantee that the pages already allocated to the table are in any particular order.

Comment: @MartinSmith lol ... well I thought you might. It *has* worked btw.  If the table was empty before the insertion it can be guaranteed (?), as this was my requirement. Thnx anyway

Answer (score 5):

If there is a auto-increment id (primary key) for that table then you can do that:

```
select top 10 * 
from mytable
order by id desc
```

Comment: Even if there is an auto-increment id (primary key) on the table, you can't be sure you query will give the last 10 inserted. For example an insert could have been done that specified a value of -1 the identity field with set identity_insert on

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636585/2858777

with bottom as(
  select top 4 *
  from tbl
  order by n desc
)
select * 
from bottom
order by n

Data source:

|  N |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |

Output:

|  N |
|----|
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a trigger.

Save the PKs for the just-inserted row in an audit table, along with an increasing index of some kind (identity is probably enough). Delete the oldest when there are more than 10 rows.

Then join the audit table to the original table to get the full 10 rows.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL you could use `select * from table LIMIT 0,10`