# Opposite of SELECT TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

Transact-SQL has a handy `SELECT TOP 4 [whatever] FROM.........`

I want to make a SELECT query returning the last "n" entries from a table instead of the first ones.

This is the query I would use to return the first four items entered at the table, using SELECT TOP:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 4 [news_title], [news_date_added], [news_short_description],
[news_ID] FROM [Web_Xtr_News] WHERE ([news_type] = 2 OR [news_type] = 3) AND
[news_language] = '" + Language + "' ORDER BY [news_ID] ASC"
```

I need to return the last four.

Comment: You should never construct SQL like that - use parameterized queries to avoid the risk of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Order in the reverse direction?

Comment: Please read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection

Comment: You might consider reading the documentation that "M$" produces, since this is clearly explained there. You should also try to avoid using derogatory nicknames for the vendors of the products you use, it's quite insulting and childish.

Comment: Thanks for the silly comments.

injection would not be possible, "language" is a hard coded string, and nothing to do with user input.

Aaron - im sure Microsoft are going to be massively insulted yes....

Oded - i dont do a great deal of SQL, i was unaware that was the order of execution.
SQL is a standard yes, but MySQL and MSSQL have differing syntaxes, surely they could use a new keyword...

Comment: Silly argument. If it is a standard they can't simply invent a new keyword and still call it SQL. FYI - Aaron works for MS, so you have insulted him. We don't have enough context to _know_ that injection is not possible. If you do such a great deal of SQL, you shouldn't even be asking this question. And of course the different clauses are evaluated at a specific order - this is all documented. Perhaps you should study a bit of the internals of the SQL execution engine.

Comment: I said "I dont do a great deal of SQL". The SQL is in a VB.NET CodeBehind file, and the language variable comed from within the sane function. Im sure Aaron will be able to sleep tonight. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: What programming language in that example? C#?

Answer (score 42):

Change the order of the table from `ASC` to `DESC`.

Comment: surely that will just return the top 4, but reverse THEIR order?

Comment: @BaronVonPeterWright - Did you bother trying? The `WHERE` "executes" before the `TOP`.

Comment: The performance of `TOP` vs `TOP` with an `ORDER BY` is important. The former returns instantaneously while the later has to order first before getting the top *N* rows.

Answer (score 22):

It's exactly this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c813/1

```
with bottom as(  
  select top 4 *
  from tbl
  order by n desc
)
select * 
from bottom
order by n
```

Data source:

```
|  N |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
```

Output:

```
|  N |
|----|
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
```

Answer (score 15):

Continue to use TOP, and reverse the order:

```
SELECT TOP 4 [news_title],
             [news_date_added],
             [news_short_description],
             [news_ID]
FROM   [Web_Xtr_News]
WHERE  ([news_type] = 2
         OR [news_type] = 3)
       AND [news_language] = @Language
ORDER  BY [news_ID] DESC
```

(It was rewritten to use parameters of course. Your original is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)

Comment: Because ordering can be expensive.

Comment: @thisismydesign Too bad it's a requirement in the question. How would you define "first" or "last" in an unordered set without specifying an order?

Comment: I think the expectation of OP was that there exists something like `BOTTOM` as the opposite of `TOP`. It'd make sense if you have an index by e.g. `asc` not to have to reorder the records to `desc` just to take the last item. So to be more precise: "Why not continue to use TOP, and reverse the order?" - Because it requires an *additional ordering which can be expensive. I understand this is not possible, just wanted to entertain your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the ordering by using `DESC` instead of `ASC` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to select batches from a list is to create a unique identifier like a (ROW ID) as (1, 2, 3, etc.) and create a nested query.

```sql
Select *
from
(select
   row_number() as id
   ,column1
   ,column2
from
  table1
)as D
where D.id (<>=! between)
```

Comment: While it is possible to get the desired rows with this approach, it adds a lot of overhead and will have performance issues on any significant volumes of data.  It assigns a value to every possible row, based on an order, then uses an additional where clause to filter.  This can prevent indexes from being used.  In addition, you'd still need to change the Order By to Desc when assigning the row_number, which is the same answer for the OP.  There is zero benefit to using this approach.