# Select latest record/row from a table without any unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [opposite of “top” in sql server, without using order by, there are no keys/indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712000/opposite-of-top-in-sql-server-without-using-order-by-there-are-no-keys-indic)

How can I select last created row from a SQL Server table that hasn't got an id/unique column.

Is it possible to somehow?

Comment: What else do you have have? Any timestamp? Without an incremental id or timestamp, the row order is, by definition, non-deterministic.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski assume that there is nothing to use. i wonder if any default function or way exist.

Comment: If there is **no ID** and **no date/timestamp** - no, there's no way to know/find out which is the last inserted row... SQL Server doesn't have any "magic" internal ordering or row-stamping or anything - if you don't provide it - then there's nothing to go on.

Comment: I see that there is no way or "magic" :) Thanks.